# How can i make the following $query work Using DISTINCT on Enrollments.Quiz_id to get rid of the double-triple records

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

```
SELECT SUM(ticketfee * enrolledplayers)
FROM Quiz
 INNER JOIN Enrollment on DISTINCT(Quiz.id) AND Quiz.id=Enrollment.Quiz_id
WHERE (Quiz.state=3 OR Quiz.state=4) AND Enrollment.promocoupon_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Quiz.id), SUM(ticketfee * enrolledplayers)
FROM Quiz
JOIN Enrollment on Quiz.id = Enrollment.Quiz_id
WHERE (Quiz.state=3 OR Quiz.state=4) AND Enrollment.promocoupon_id IS NULL
```

Comment: sorry for not helping you understand what exactly i wanted but this is not waht i needed..as a result i want only the sum from the quiz table...but i have to check that on the enrollment table the promocoupon is null.Problem is that on enrollment table there are more than one  quizes with same quiz_id